# Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Estou com um problema simples na hora de pegar um dado de uma tabela..

O erro é

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in

Código:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT diasvip FROM login WHERE userid = ".$_POST['userid']."");
    while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Dias Vip do Usuário: ".$exibe['diasvip']."</div>";  
    }
    mysqli_close($conexao);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse erro é lançado porque a consulta não foi executada corretamente, antes de entrar no `While(..) {...}`, verifique o resultado retornado:

```
if($sql === FALSE) {
    // Consulta falhou, parar aqui 
    die(mysqli_error());
}
```

Seu código deve assim:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT diasvip FROM login WHERE userid = '".$_POST['userid']."'");
if($sql === FALSE) { 
   die(mysqli_error());
}

while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Dias Vip do Usuário: ".$exibe['diasvip']."</div>";  
}
mysqli_close($conexao);
```

Comment: se eu tirar essas " ele deixa o restante inteiro do código inexecutavel mano lolz. Basta checar a sua codebox, a parte debaixo fica com a cor vermelha sem as "

Comment: @Guilherme Veja se agora funciona. :)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Valeu bro S2

Comment: @Guilherme Se funcionou então, marque a resposta como aceita, clique na marca logo abaixo da pontuação, isso ajuda os futuros visitantes com problemas parecidos a saber qual resposta deu certo para você. =)

Comment: Curti essa galinha preta do avatar, estilo tribal. Só não saquei qual é a do logo dos transformers no meio. É de algum dos filmes? Só assisti o 1o (logo mais deleto o comment)

Comment: @Bacco Difícil ter assistido só o 1º =) essa é a logo dos *Decepticons*.

Comment: Entao, o **["logo" dos decepticons](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=decepticons&tbm=isch)** eu conheço (o 1o desenho "longa" dos transformers eu vi no cinema, tou ficando velho), não conhecia esse treco tribal em volta.

Comment: @Bacco A [imaginação é o limite](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=decepticons+tattoo&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=jNP7VIT3O-TIsQSk2oKoDA&ved=0CBsQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=677#tbm=isch&tbs=rimg%3ACYq03QadHxd0Ijg0k6Kx9RKGpjS3g6sLYMFSuz4PjQaFiplz1Gw2HFutrOdDyjPifkaLf-9ZBOcdOrILUUrB9tF93ioSCTSTorH1EoamEbsj6u8zocu1KhIJNLeDqwtgwVIRkVmqHRXibJcqEgm7Pg-NBoWKmRGtrrxj6hMbbyoSCXPUbDYcW62sEblIX3VEjSOBKhIJ50PKM-J-RosRk64_1LGvAG3YqEgl_171kE5x06shGr-LV5Sz-WiyoSCQtRSsH20X3eEXlIRO7lbddq&q=decepticons%20tattoo&imgdii=_). o/

Comment: Aliás, na versão em inglês do longa, a voz do Galvatron é do [Leonard Nimoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Nimoy)

Comment: @Bacco Eu não sabia desse fato não.. pesquisando mais sobre isso, ele também fez a voz de [Sentinel](http://www.comingsoon.net/movies/news/75809-leonard-nimoy-is-the-voice-of-sentinel-prime) no *Transformers: O Lado Oculto da Lua*.

Answer (score 3):

Esse erro acontece quando sua consulta retorna um erro, para debugar isso crie uma variável com a sql imprima ela e teste direto no banco também ative exibe os erros ao executar a consulta com [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

```
$str_consulta = "SELECT diasvip FROM login WHERE userid = ".$_POST['userid']);
echo $str_consulta;
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, $str_consulta)  or die(mysqli_error($db));
```