# Problema com o PHP

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno banco de dados para armazenar algumas coisas, depois de feito as programações me surgiu um erro cujo eu não consigo visualizar sua solução, poderia alguém me fornecer ajuda?

Mensagem de erro:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\Aula\index.php on line 62

Codigo da index:

Modal

## Listar Cursos

Cadastrar
            
            
            
                
                    
                        
                            ×
                            Cadastrar Curso
                        
                        
                            
                                
                                    Nome:
                                    
                                
                                
                                    Detalhes:
                                    
                                
                                
                                    Cadastrar

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Nome do Curso</th>
                            <th>Ação</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_cursos)){ ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $rows_cursos['id']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $rows_cursos['nome']; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $rows_cursos['id']; ?>">Visualizar</button>

                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<?php echo $rows_cursos['id']; ?>" data-whatevernome="<?php echo $rows_cursos['nome']; ?>"  data-whateverdetalhes="<?php echo $rows_cursos['detalhes']; ?>">Editar</button>

                                    <a href="processa_apagar.php?id=<?php echo $rows_cursos['id']; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Apagar</button></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- Inicio Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $rows_cursos['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $rows_cursos['nome']; ?></h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p><?php echo $rows_cursos['id']; ?></p>
                                            <p><?php echo $rows_cursos['nome']; ?></p>
                                            <p><?php echo $rows_cursos['detalhes']; ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Fim Modal -->
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                 </table>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>



    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cursos</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="http://localhost/Aula/processa.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Nome:</label>
                            <input name="nome" type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Detalhes:</label>
                            <textarea name="detalhes" class="form-control" id="detalhes-text"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id_curso">
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Alterar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>





    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
            var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
            var recipientnome = button.data('whatevernome')
            var recipientdetalhes = button.data('whateverdetalhes')
            // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
            // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
            var modal = $(this)
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('ID do Curso: ' + recipient)
            modal.find('#id_curso').val(recipient)
            modal.find('#recipient-name').val(recipientnome)
            modal.find('#detalhes-text').val(recipientdetalhes)
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Veja também [Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53443/70)