# Erro mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tendo um problema com estes erros:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hpveiculos\index.php on line 512
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hpveiculos\index.php on line 516
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hpveiculos\index.php on line 526

Código:

```
<?php
$filtros="";
if (isset($_GET['filtro_cat'])){
    if ($_GET['filtro_cat']!=''){
        $filtros="&& cat='".$_GET['filtro_cat']."'";

                $qr=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(valor) as total FROM movimentos WHERE tipo=1 && mes='$mes_hoje' && ano='$ano_hoje' $filtros");
                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($qr);
                $entradas=$row['total'];

                $qr=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(valor) as total FROM movimentos WHERE tipo=0 && mes='$mes_hoje' && ano='$ano_hoje' $filtros");
                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($qr);
                $saidas=$row['total'];

                $resultado_mes=$entradas-$saidas;

        }
}

$qr=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM movimentos WHERE mes='$mes_hoje' && ano='$ano_hoje' $filtros ORDER By dia");
$cont=0;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qr)) {
$cont++;

$cat = $row['categoria_id'];
$qr2=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nome FROM categorias WHERE id='$cat'");
$row2=mysqli_fetch_array($qr2);
$categoria=$row2['nome'];

?>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro no MySQL "expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28184/erro-no-mysql-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in) ... [Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53443/)

Comment: Isso acontece basicamente porque alguma SQL sua está errada. Para mais detalhes use a função `mysqli_error`.

Answer (score 0):

Como o pessoal disse.
Esse erro acontece porque seu SQL está errado, tenta dar uma verificada na variável $filtros.